# how to check build command result like pipeline

Tags: jenkins, plugins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-plugins

I want to check build command results in my test project like in the pipeline project. This is what pipeline [looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LdiYj.jpg).

Now, I don't use pipeline job. I only have Freestyle projects, but I looked in the pipeline project, and I could see the results for every stage on the project's summary page.

I cant use many plugins like in the pipeline project, but I still want to see the results for every build command on my current project's summary page.

Is there a similar plugin like the ones pipeline is using?

Comment: This is not possible in freestyle jobs. The whole purpose of pipelines or workflows as known earlier is to provide more flexibility and control by breaking down a linear and rigid build job into logically distinct and flexible stages that you can also visualize more comprehensively in the GUI. Freestyle jobs just don’t support this.

Comment: @DibakarAditya thanks to your answer. you say it doesn't exist similar plugin...I understand..